# Should I use weakSelf in private convenience methods when they are called by block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

The title almost covers it. I understand why use weakSelf inside blocks.

But imagine a situation where we have a view controller. The view controller calls a data API (a singleton shared instance) which has a completion block. So in this call VC provides a completion block to which the VC doesn't hold a reference. 
There is also a private convenience method inside VC which does something to a UI component and calls self.
But this private convenience method is called inside the block.

So knowing that, should I use weakSelf in the convenience method too?

Comment: The key point: does self have a strong reference to the completion block. If it doesn't there is no need for weakSelf. If you are unsure implement the `deallocate` method and see it it is called.

Comment: In most cases temporary retain cycle is okay.

Comment: @Andy Indeed, a retain cycle can be broken manually. This is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would use `weakSelf` pattern wherever:

- You would otherwise have a strong reference cycle;
- You are using cancelable asynchronous tasks and wish to cancel them in `dealloc`; or
- If the view controller is dismissed while the asynchronous call is still underway, you do not want it retained for the duration of the asynchronous call.

This latter point means that one may use `weakSelf` pattern in conjunction with completion blocks for asynchronous methods, regardless of whether there is a strong reference cycle or not. The question is simply whether you need the view controller retained for the duration of the asynchronous call even if the view controller has since been dismissed.

Comment: Ok so from what I understand, there is no clear cut  one answer, it depend on the expectation about the app's state. In my particular case, there is no point to try to set the UI component if the VC has been dismissed. In other words, the VC dismissal renders this UI component update useless. So I would go with weakSelf?

Comment: I personally would. Furthermore, if the asynchronous task exists solely for the purpose of updating a UI component, I always also ask myself whether it makes sense to make it cancelable operation. If it's something trivial, it may not be worth it. But if it's computationally expensive (e.g. complicated image processing, slow or complicated network requests, etc.), I use `weakSelf` and cancel it in `dealloc`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you do not store the block into a property of `self` (or into an object referring `self` and so on). So there is no reason at all to use `weakSelf`, because a retain cycle cannot be built.